# How to get Facebook page feed and Filter its fields as Json using Google App script

Tags: facebook-graph-api, google-apps-script, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to get a Facebook page feed through Google app script.
As of now I tried different scripts but I am getting only app token with the request and if i change it with a usertoken from graph api I got messages but no images and titles

How to get the user token and get the correct fields for as a json ,

```
  var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com'
  + '/love.to.traavel/feed'
  + '?access_token='+ encodeURIComponent(getToken());
 // + '?access_token=' + service.getAccessToken();

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});

var json = response.getContentText();
var jsondata = JSON.parse(json);
Logger.log(jsondata);  //check this and adjust following for loop and ht



var posts = {};

 for (var i in jsondata) {
    posts[i] = {"post":jsondata[i].message};
 }

 return posts;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You should use a Page Token, not a User Token
- You need to ask for fields you want to get, with the `fields` parameter: `https://graph.facebook.com/love.to.traavel/feed?fields=field1,field2,...&access_token=xxx`

You get a user token by authorizing your App: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/platforms

Be aware that extended user tokens are valid for 60 days only, so you have to refresh it once in a while. There is no user token that is valid forever. You cannot authorize through code only, it needs user interaction. The easiest way is to just generate a user token by selecting your App in the API Explorer and authorize it, like you did already. Then hardcode it in the script code.

Alternatively, you can try implementing this with the manual login flow, check out the docs for that. You can try adding the functionality using this for a custom interface where you go through the login process: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

Since you don´t own the page, you should read this too: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS

Comment: Getting page token for a public page is not possible as I am not an admin of it .As of now I can get the Public page feeds using my App with user token , So how to request user auth token from the above code , right now I am getting App token